# How to refer a cell in vlookup when that cell is deleted everyday & next cell takes its place?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vlookup

I was working on creating some dashboard for my client in which I have to put some formulas that can automatically hold the values as itis whenever the very first row is been deleted everyday.
I have figured out most of the part but stuck on Vlookup.

Suppose I have a table from A1:D10. I have to refer this table with vlookup & refer cell A1 for datalookup.
Everyday I have to delete entire A Column & the data of B column takes over to replace A.
Now issue is Vlookup is throwing error #NA whenever i am deleting the column.

Please help me out if any one....

i have already tried index match, indirect & offset but nothing works.

Just want my Vlookup can read the data from the column B which replaces the column A & becomes column A in the table.

Comment: You said you tried `=INDIRECT` and it was not working? Because it is working for me. What did you enter into the cell referenced by `INDIRECT`?

Comment: Right now I'm working with this but this one also giving error when i delete the first line.INDEX($C$4:$D$7,MATCH(B12,$C$4:$C$7,0),2)

Comment: are you manually deleting it or using VBA to delete it?  If you are already in VBA you can have VBA write to formula for you with reference to column A again.